# What is an 'executable form'?

Tags: python, forms, executable

I'm fairly new to programming but I was wondering what 'executable form' meant & how to convert a Python file into an executable form.

Comment: Add details for the question, not clear what u expect

Comment: Give us some context, please? Where did you see the phrase 'executable form'?

Comment: It was on my assignment briefing sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that whoever wrote that meant to set the executable bit on the file. To do that on most UNIX platforms, you'll need to go into some kind of shell and run this:

```
chmod +x /full/path/to/file.py
```

(note that the full path is not actually required — you can use a relative path, too)

If you've done that and the file starts with an appropriate hashbang like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you should be able to run the script very easily:

```
./file.py
```

(assuming your working directory is the same as the directory in which `file.py` is located)

Answer (score 0):

On windows platform, "executable form" means PE files, more specifically, ".exe" files.
Maybe you can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to convert a py script to an exe file.